# Problem formatting USB Drive

Tags: permissions, format, usb-drive

I am unable to format a USB drive. I tried changing the permissions by using the command below:

```
/media$ sudo chmod 777 F84E-1690
```

"F84E-1690" is the drive name. But it gives below message:

```
chmod: changing permissions of `F84E-1690': Read-only file system
```

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Try *gparted partition Editor* to format the usb to **fat32 filesystem**.
After formatting remove the pendrive and reinsert it.I think it would works.

Comment: You said `its` an external HDD, @RPiAwesomeness . Formatting it to FAT32 **is** a good idea, as it will then work with Windows and Linux straight away. Ext is good, but will not work well with Windows, whilst NTFS is just annoying - I upvoted, which if anything gives him more rep (-1 for downvote, +10 for upvote) I think.

Answer (score 0):

- Type `mount` and check if filesystem is mounted in readonly
- If filesystem is readonly : `unmount /media/F84E-1690` and check filesystem : `fsck -f /dev/DEVICE`
- Mount again `mount -t TYPE /dev/DEVICE /media/DIR rw`

To format, use fdisk and mkfs.xxx (mkfs.ext4, mkfs.ntfs, mkfs.msdos,..)

- `mkfs.xxx /dev/PARTITION`

For fdisk, check here : http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to identify your device designation (sort of /sdx, where x is a letter a, b, c, etc..), then it would be wise to erase the data using dd, so in terminal type sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx where x is the designation letter of the device you wish to wipe. After doing so (it'll take a while depending on the volume size) then enter the disk utility and format the drive. Then you'll be done.